# react native vector icons and fonts won't show after building apk

Tags: react-native, expo, custom-font

custom font and icons from @expo/vector-icons not showing after building the apk. they do show on development using expo-font aync load.

how to load the font and the custom fonts while using apk without app crashing. currently images are loaded from assets folder perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

When packaging your app for production, you have to bundle the font assets. This can be done by following these steps:

1. Copy your fonts to "assets/fonts", your fonts should have the file extension of "ttf" or "otf"
2. When using rn < 0.60 run `npx react-native link`
3. In Android Studio navigate to "app/src/main" and create an assets folder, if it doesn't exist already
4. Copy your fonts folder ("assets/fonts") to the newly created assets folder inside your Android Studio project
5. Create a react-native.config.js file with these contents:

```
module.exports = {
  assets: ['./assets/fonts/'],
};
```

6. Install react-native-vector-icons using `npm install react-native-vector-icons`
7. Follow additional steps mentioned for android [react-native-vector-icons](https://github.com/oblador/react-native-vector-icons?tab=readme-ov-file#android-setup)
8. Use Icons and your own font, e.g. using:

```
StyleSheet.create({
    someText: {
        fontFamily: "MyFont"
    }
});
```

Reference: [medium.com](https://dharasapariya.medium.com/a-guide-on-using-custom-fonts-in-react-native-android-6ef20d88c75f)

Comment: this method seems not to work. am using "@expo/vector-icons": "^13.0.0".
Here is how am loading custom fonts
`
import { loadAsync } from "expo-font"; 
`

`
  useEffect(() => {
    async function loadFonts() {
      await loadAsync({
        "MamaKilo Black": require("../../assets/fonts/MamaKilo_Decorative.otf"),
      });
      setFontsLoaded(true);
    }

    loadFonts();
  }, []);
`

Comment: Ah you only mentioned react-native-vector-icons in the title instead of expo/vector-icons. Have you followed the steps described [here](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/font/#configuration-in-appjsonappconfigjs)?